# Two JPanel inside JPanel layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I trying to divide my `JFrame` to 3 parts:

- Two parts using `JSplitPane` and inside each part of split pane I'm adding a `JPanel`
- Inside one of these panels I'm inserting two panels using `GridBagLayout`

I have problem when I add some components inside the second panel - it causes me an update in size of `panel2`

My screen before adding components in `panel2`:

[image]

After adding component in `panel2`:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code? A [mcve] would allow us to solve your problem ...

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the preferred size of both panels of the split pane to zero to see if it helps. Like :   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));

Comment: Debugging a code I can't see that's an art I yet have to learn.